# How to make multiple queries to DB and return to one array

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

## How to make multiple queries to bd and return to one array

The bottom line is that searches for tickets, from one city to another, also take information about the bus brand.

In my controller, I'm doing the following:

```
public function search() {

    // Sets the parameters from the get request to the variables.
    $from_city = Request::get('from');
    $to_city   = Request::get('to');

    //Finds the city ID
    $from_id   = DB::table('city')->where('name', $from_city)->pluck('id');
    $to_id     = DB::table('city')->where('name', $to_city)->pluck('id');
    $date      = Request::get('date');

    //Find a tickets using Query Builder
    $result = DB::table('tickets')
        ->select(DB::raw("*"))
        ->where('from_city_id', '=', $from_id)
        ->where('to_city_id', '=', $to_id)
        ->where('date', '=', $date)
        ->get();


    return view('index.search', ['tickets' => $result]);
}
```

Also, I have a view that has the following:

```
@foreach ($tickets as $ticket)
    From city id: {{ $ticket->from_city_id }}
    To city id: {{ $ticket->to_city_id }}
    Date: {{ $ticket->date }}
    Bus number: 
    From city name
    To city name:
@endforeach
```

I need to display the city_name, bus_number data from the identifier, they are in a separate database tables, how do I do this to be displayed in the view?

## database photos:

**Bus Table**

[image: bus table]

**City Table**

[image: city table]

**Tickets Table**

[image: tickets table]

## ***I will be very grateful for your help!***

Comment: how is the bus related to the city? Is there a relationship? You haven't explained how they are connected. You should be able to use some sort of JOIN query to bring back the related rows.

Comment: forgot to add is a search for tickets, from one city to another

Comment: that doesn't answer my question. What is the relationship between cities and buses? Presumably some table(s) and foreign key(s) define it? Once you know that, you can write some SQL.

Comment: If you have Models and Relationships defined, you shouldn't have to use `DB::table('tickets')`, or any `DB::` functions. You would do `Ticket::where()` or `City::where`, etc etc. Read over the documentation on https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent and https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships to get a better understanding of Models and Relationships.

Comment: ADyson, ok, edited my post, so much better?

Comment: Tim Lewis, well, thank you - I read

Comment: Is there a relation between tickets and city Models ??

Comment: Maraboc, I did not understand you ...

Comment: Is there a relation in the tickets Model like `public function fromCity()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\City');
    }` ...

Comment: Maraboc, I think I'll do it

Comment: @Ostap34PHP  You need to join to the cities table twice using the from/to City IDs matching the ID in the City table, and the same to the bus table using the Bus ID matching in each of the tables. I don't know the specific syntax for the PHP DB library you're using, but its documentation should have examples showing you how to write it.  The underlying SQL concept is an INNER JOIN.

Comment: ADyson, thank you very much! I will read about these sql functions